# Evaluate this complex integral

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, mathematical-physics, complex-integration

I have the following complex integral that corresponds to a complex integral of a [Wigner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) of a 1-mode Gaussian state:

$$I_n(\sigma) = \int^\infty_{-\infty} d^2\alpha \; L_n \left(\frac{4|\alpha|^2}{2 - \sigma}\right) \exp\left\{\frac{2\sigma |\alpha|^2}{\sigma - 2}\right\} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(\alpha - \lambda)^\top V^{-1}(\alpha - \lambda)\right\},$$

where $\alpha$ is a complex variable, $d^2\alpha = d\Re(\alpha)d\Im(\alpha)$, $\lambda$ and $V$ are the first (mean) and second (covariance) moments of the Gaussian state defined through:

$$\lambda = (a, b)^\top, \quad V = \begin{pmatrix} 
c & d \\
d & e 
\end{pmatrix},$$

where the coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$ are general complex numbers, and $L_n(x)$ are the [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials).

I am aware that this type of integral is usually evaluated by using polar coordinates. However, I am unsure how to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated. Even a method that obtains the solution numerically is fine.